# Need help to understand topological color codes

Tags: topological-quantum-computing

I am doing work on topological color codes, but after searching a lot of papers I could not find one that explained some points. Why do we need the colors for? Why do we have different types of color paths and what makes them different? If we have two different color paths with the same error that cross a qubit, does the qubit get corrected or not? What does it mean that their paths anticommute on that point?